# Count() not working as expected in SQL

Tags: sql, count, sql-server-2014

A coworker put together a table for me that I need for mapping data, and table consists of two fields,  OP_ID and BillType.  In theory, there should be a one-to-one correspondence between the two:  every Op_ID should have one and only one bill type.

When I started using it, however, I noticed that there were duplicate OP_IDs with different BillTypes.  E.g:

```
OP_Id               BillType 
007a000v9GWkAAM BillReady 
007a000v9GWkAAM RateReady
```

So first I built a query to group the data into unique combinations of IDs and BillTypes:

```
SELECT OP_ID, BillType
FROM MappingTable
GROUP BY OP_ID, BillType
```

Simple enough.  This set should and does include the above two records.  Then, I wrapped another query around this to count OP_Ids within the aggregated dataset.  Theoretically, any OP_ID with more than one BillType should occur twice, and so it should return a count > 1.  Right?

```
SELECT OP_ID, BillType, Count(OP_ID)
FROM 
    (
    SELECT OP_ID, BillType
    FROM MappingTable
    GROUP BY OP_ID, BillType
    ) Base
GROUP BY  OP_ID, BillType
HAVING Count(OP_ID) > 1
```

But this query returns nothing whatsoever.  Here's what even more baffling:  when I remove the HAVING clause and limit the query to pull only the above OP_ID, since I already know it's a dupe, where's what I get:

```
OP_ID          BillType  CountOfOP_IDs
007a000v9GWkAAM BillReady   1
007a000v9GWkAAM RateReady   1
```

So there are clearly two records for OP_ID 007a000v9GWkAAM, but SQL is counting only one!

This seems so simple, and I'm sure I'm just missing something basic about how COUNT() works. For reference, I'm working on SQL Server 2014 and both columns are nvarchar.  I've also confirmed that SQL evaluates the OP_IDs in both records as identical.  Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 4):

Count counts the number of rows that have been grouped into one. Just remove bill type from the outer group by.

Also look at the count distinct option. That might be easier.

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
SELECT OP_ID, BillType
FROM MappingTable
GROUP BY OP_ID, BillType
```

is the long way to say

```
SELECT DISTINCT OP_ID, BillType
FROM MappingTable
```

When you now have distinct combinations of `OP_ID` and `BillType`, adding a new `GROUP BY` on those two fields will do nothing.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT OP_ID, BillType
       FROM MappingTable
     ) Base
GROUP BY  OP_ID, BillType
HAVING Count(OP_ID) > 1
```

The new "groups" will all consist of 1 row from the inner `SELECT`, so `COUNT` will always be 1, meaning that `Count(OP_ID) > 1` is always false and you will get nothing returned.

---

Perhaps you meant to find `OP_Id` values with multiple `BillType` values. If so, you should drop `BillType` from the `GROUP BY`, as [suggested by @DonKirkby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36956241/5221149).

You can get two *examples* of those `BillType` values in the result by also retrieving the first and last `BillType` value, if you are interested in that (often good when researching, at least).

```
SELECT OP_ID, COUNT(*), MIN(BillType), MAX(BillType)
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT OP_ID, BillType
       FROM MappingTable
     ) Base
GROUP BY OP_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You can shorten the entire statement by using `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`, also as [suggested by @DonKirkby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36956241/5221149).

```
SELECT OP_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT BillType), MIN(BillType), MAX(BillType)
FROM MappingTable
GROUP BY OP_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT BillType) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach makes sense.  My guess is that the `OP_ID` values are subtly different -- perhaps due to encoding issues or character look-alikes.

This is easy to find.  What does this query return?

```
select mt.*
from mappingtable
where op_id = '007a000v9GWkAAM';
```

Incidentally, you can simplify your query to:

```
SELECT OP_ID
FROM MappingTable
GROUP BY OP_ID
HAVING MIN(BillType) <> MAX(BillType);
```

If you want to see the `BillType` values then add `GROUP_CONCAT(BillType)` to the `SELECT`.

EDIT:

The above is all correct, but your query doesn't work because the outer query is grouping by `OP_ID` and `BILL_TYPE`.  Try this version:

```
SELECT OP_ID, Count(OP_ID)
FROM (SELECT OP_ID, BillType
      FROM MappingTable
      GROUP BY OP_ID, BillType
      ) Base
GROUP BY OP_ID
HAVING Count(OP_ID) > 1;
```

Yours returns no rows because you are grouping on the same keys twice.  The subquery removes duplicates, so the count for the outer would always be 1.

Comment: Is there a reason for the anonymous downvote on what seems to be a correct answer?

Comment: Not the down-voter, but my guess would be that you shouldn't ask clarification questions like "What does this query return?" in an answer. --- Also, `HAVING MIN(BillType) <> MAX(BillType)` will not find `OP_ID` values where two rows exists, one with a null `BillType` and one with a value. May not be an issue if `BillType` is `NOT NULL`, but that hasn't been stated, so you're currently assuming something not in evidence.

Comment: @Andreas . . . Highly unlikely.  The question in my answer is about the data quality, which could lead to the results in the OP.  The use of `min()` and `max()` for the `having` clause is the recommended approach, assuming there are no `NULL` values -- and the question has no suggestion of `NULL` values in that column.  If someone is going downvote for those reasons, they really should explain why.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MappingTable 
WHERE OP_ID in (SELECT OP_ID 
                FROM (SELECT OP_ID, count(*) ct
                      FROM MappingTable
                      GROUP BY OP_ID)
                WHERE ct > 1)
```

There are not (at least in your example) duplicates for BOTH columns, just unexpected duplicates for OP_ID.